# Microservices code coverage with Jacoco Code Coverage

Tags: java, docker, gradle, jacoco

I have a project with subprojects (microservices using docker), build using Gradle.
Service1,Service2,Service3 are rest applications,separate modules in the project. They are started with docker-compose.yaml.
Each Rest service is run in its own container.
There is also a separate module Autotests, which contains functional and integration tests.
[Project.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXPcP.jpg)

The task is to understand how much these services are covered by the tests from the Autotests module. Jacoco is kind of good for that.
From the examples that I found, everywhere indicated a structure like this, functional tests within the module, as for example here:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/java-how-to-run-component-tests-with-code-coverage-using-gradle-and-docker-47fc023969a4

My tests go through several services at once and are in a separate module.
As advised here and in the examples, in docker-compose.yaml I made an agent:

```
agent:
image: ictu/jacoco-agent-docker:0.8.6
volumes:
  - jacoco:/jacoco:rw
```

I have set environment variables for each service:

```
 JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:"-javaagent:/jacoco/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/jacoco/service1.exec
      
    volumes:
      - jacoco:/jacoco
      - type: bind
        source: ../.../build/jacoco
        target: /temp/result
```

Made a Gradle task that collects information from a *.exec file:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    getExecutionData().setFrom(fileTree(buildDir).include("jacoco/*.exec"))
    getAdditionalSourceDirs().setFrom(projects)
    getAdditionalClassDirs().setFrom(projects)
    reports{
        html.required = true
        html.destination(file("$buildDir/jacocoHtml"))
        xml.required = true
        csv.required = true
```

But the result is that it shows the coverage as incorrect as possible. For example in Service1 this is the structure:
[Project_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JetZ4.jpg)

In jacocoReport it shows that the "api" folder is 0% covered, although there are tests for methods in this folder and they are in the Autotests module.

If anyone has any idea how to fix it, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Did you find the solution for it?